# how can i disable Text boxes when checkbox is checked and enable them when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields of type text and i want to disable them when i check the checkbox and enable them when i uncheck the checkbox using jquery

Here is my code :

```
 <div class="col-md-11" id="worktimeID">
                <input  type="text" name="From_1" class="time" placeholder="00:00" />
                <input type="text" name="To_1" class="time" placeholder="00:00" />
                <input type="checkbox" id="checked"/><label>Day Off ?</label>

            </div>
```

My jquery code:

```
$("#checked").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var worktime = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
            var allTextBoxes = $(worktime).children('[type=text]');

            alert(allTextBoxes);
            allTextBoxes.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            var worktime = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
            var allTextBoxes = $('[type=text]');
            $('#checked').attr('checked', false);
            allTextBoxes.prop('disabled', false);

        }


    });
```

Comment: [jQuery on](https://api.jquery.com/on), [jQuery prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop) to toggle the disabled property

Comment: can you please clarify using code ?

Comment: No, because you have not shown an attempt at solving this yourself.  StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  You have to make an attempt, and ask questions about the issues you encounter.  Pleave review [ask] for more information about the details you should include in your questions to help us help you.

Comment: i actually tried to make it but it did not work

Comment: Then show us what you tried that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. `worktime` is just the id, without the hash.  But a selector needs the hash.
2. Your not even using the `worktime` in the else so not sure why you are doing that.

   ```
   $("#checked").click(function () {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           var worktime = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
                              // #1
           var allTextBoxes = $('#'+ worktime).children('[type=text]');

           alert(allTextBoxes);
           allTextBoxes.prop('disabled', true);
       }
       else {
           // #2
           var worktime = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
           var allTextBoxes = $('[type=text]');
           $('#checked').attr('checked', false);
           allTextBoxes.prop('disabled', false);

       }
   });
   ```
3. In any case, this logic can be reduced, since if the checkbox is checked, they should be disabled.  If it is not checked, it is not disabled.

   ```js
       $("#checked").click(function() {
         $(this).closest("div").find(':text').prop('disabled', this.checked);
       });
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="col-md-11" id="worktimeID">
         <input type="text" name="From_1" class="time" placeholder="00:00" />
         <input type="text" name="To_1" class="time" placeholder="00:00" />
         <input type="checkbox" id="checked" /><label>Day Off ?</label>
       </div>
   ```